# Pycharm 2 раза выводит результат кода

Tags: python, pycharm

Код:

```py
for x in range(5):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print(x)
```

Когда запускаю в pycharm выводит:

```
0
2
4
0
2
4
```

Comment: Может, вы не весь код привели?

Comment: Весь, если даже print(5) ввести, то выдаст 5 5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231720/double-printing-in-pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Код работает правильно. Скорее всего проблема с твоим PyCharm.
Попробуй кэш PyCharm'a почистить. File - Invalidate caches

Answer (score 0):

При создании проекта нужна поставить галку Create a main.pu welcome script во вкладке custom environment. Тогда команда будет выполняться 1 раз